# Location and timeframe matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, laravel, optimization

I am developing a B2C service on demand and I need to create the matching algorithm, simple yet efficient enough to run on a Laravel backend.

The service matches house cleaners with customers, where the customer, when booking, defines a certain date and timeframe when (s)he will be available at home.
On the other hand (#1), cleaners don't have a working schedule and should be picked according to geographical proximity and, of course, availability (not to have two services starting at the same time or too close time-wise one from the other).
Obviously, there should be a geographical limit so that after a certain ε km the algorithm stops searching and, according to the type of service chosen, there is a specific duration.

Another solution (#2) could be to have a predefined weekly schedule and match schedules in order to define a "working calendar" as new requests come.

In any case the cleaner can opt not to accept a booking, in that case the algorithm will continue searching for another possible candidate.

Which algorithm would you suggest for solution #1 and #2?
Thank you

Comment: A simple brute force linear search would suffice. I think this is more of a system architecture question than an algorithm one.

Comment: How to combine and maximize schedules? Any reference or suggested reading?